# R - Adding numbers within a data frame cell together

Tags: r, dataframe, addition, coercion

I have a data frame in which the values are stored as characters. However, many values contain two numbers that need to be added together. Example:

```
                    2014 Q1 Sales   2014 Q2 Sales   2014 Q3 Sales   2014 Q4 Sales 
  Product 1                  3+6            2+10               8            13+2
  Product 2                    6             4+0            <NA>               5
  Product 3                 <NA>             5+9             3+1              11
```

Is there a way to go through the whole data frame and replace all cells containing characters like "3+6" with new values equal to their sum? I assume this would involve coercing the characters to numeric or integers, but I don't know how that would be possible for values with the + sign in them. I would like the example data frame to end up looking like this:

```
                    2014 Q1 Sales   2014 Q2 Sales   2014 Q3 Sales   2014 Q4 Sales 
  Product 1                    9              12               8              15
  Product 2                    6               4            <NA>               5
  Product 3                 <NA>              14               4              11
```

Comment: This would be easier to work with if you used `dput` to give a machine-readable representation of your example.

Comment: This might be a first: a time when I'm actually tempted to recommend `eval(parse(text = ...))`, assuming you really can't get the data in a nicer form.

Comment: @joran That was what I was going for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an easier example:

```
dat <- data.frame(a=c("3+6", "10"), b=c("12", NA), c=c("3+4", "5+6"))
dat
##      a    b   c
##  1 3+6   12 3+4
##  2  10 <NA> 5+6

apply(dat, 1:2, function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))
##       a  b  c
## [1,]  9 12  7
## [2,] 10 NA 11
```

Using R itself to do the computation with `eval` and `parse` does the trick.

Comment: That's cleaner than the nested `lapply`, `sapply` I was thinking of, since they likely won't care about the coercion from `apply`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with `gsubfn` without using `eval(parse`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'matrix' (`as.matrix(dat)`).  We match the numbers (`[0-9]+`), capture it as a group using parentheses (`(..)`) followed by `+`, followed by second set of numbers, and replace it by converting to `numeric` class and then do the `+`.  The output can be assigned back to the original dataset to get the same structure as in 'dat'.

```
library(gsubfn)
dat[] <- as.numeric(gsubfn('([0-9]+)\\+([0-9]+)', 
                  ~as.numeric(x)+as.numeric(y), as.matrix(dat)))

dat
#          2014 Q1 Sales 2014 Q2 Sales 2014 Q3 Sales 2014 Q4 Sales
#Product 1             9            12             8            15
#Product 2             6             4            NA             5
#Product 3            NA            14             4            11
```

Or we can loop the columns with `lapply` and perform the replacement with `gsubfn` for each of the columns.

```
 dat[] <- lapply(dat, function(x) as.numeric(gsubfn('([0-9]+)\\+([0-9]+)', 
        ~as.numeric(x)+as.numeric(y),  as.character(x))))
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(`2014 Q1 Sales` = structure(c(1L, 2L, NA), .Label = c("3+6", 
"6"), class = "factor"), `2014 Q2 Sales` = structure(1:3, .Label = c("2+10", 
"4+0", "5+9"), class = "factor"), `2014 Q3 Sales` = structure(c(2L, 
NA, 1L), .Label = c("3+1", "8"), class = "factor"), `2014 Q4 Sales` = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 1L), .Label = c("11", "13+2", "5"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("2014 Q1 Sales", 
"2014 Q2 Sales", "2014 Q3 Sales", "2014 Q4 Sales"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Product 1", 
"Product 2", "Product 3"))
```